# Regarding unique username

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am dealing with a student portal in which i have to create a unique login username for students. I have their firstname, lastname and DOB in a csv file. I tried to create a unique username using these three params for uniqueness. But it is possible that DOB will be null so it may conflict.

Also some of students which are user of portal for one session i.e for ex: 2012-13 will have details in csv sheet of 2013-14 and if we use same format with any unique timestamp or unique id, for username generation than there will be two username of same user.

I need a solution from which i generate a unique username with available details also can check that a every student enters in database only one time and have only one username.

I hope i am clear with details if not than please give your comments i will improve it.

below is the code which i used to generate Username from csv data ,

Logic - USERNAME = 'first 3 letter of firstname' + 'DOB' + 'first 3 letter of lastname'

```
            foreach($result as $file_data){
                    //loop throgh the data and find errors

                //check the duplicate entry in the file
                if(count($accepted)>0){
                    foreach($accepted as $accepted_user){

                        if(($file_data['First name'] == $accepted_user['First name']) && ($file_data['Last name'] == $accepted_user['Last name']) && ($file_data['DOB'] == $accepted_user['DOB'] )){
                            $rejected[]=array("error"=> $this->lang->line('duplicate_entry_in_file'),"line_number"=>$error_count);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Generate username from Firstname , Lastname & DOB (if null than we add auto generated DOB)
                    if($file_data['First name']=='' || $file_data['Last name']==''){ // check if first_name last_name and date-of_birth is empty
                        $rejected[]=array("error"=> "First Name , Last Name not available","line_number"=>$error_count);
                    }else{
                        if($file_data['DOB']==''){
                            $dob=date('dmy',mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")+1,date("Y")-10)); //
                            $date_of_birth= $dob['4'].$dob['5']."-".$dob['2'].$dob['3']."-".$dob['0'].$dob['1'];
                            $dob_username= $dob['0'].$dob['1']."-".$dob['4'].$dob['3']."-".$dob['4'].$dob['5'];
                        }else{
                            $dob = $file_data['DOB'];
                           if(strlen($dob) == 5 ){
                                $year_of_birth=$dob['3'].$dob['4'];

                                if($year_of_birth < date('y')){
                                    $date_of_birth= "20".$dob['3'].$dob['4']."-".$dob['1'].$dob['2']."-0".$dob['0'];
                                    $dob_username= "0-".$dob['0']."-".$dob['1'].$dob['2']."20".$dob['3'].$dob['4'];
                                }elseif($year_of_birth > date('y')){
                                    $date_of_birth= "19".$dob['3'].$dob['4']."-".$dob['1'].$dob['2']."-0".$dob['0'];
                                    $dob_username= "0-".$dob['0']."-".$dob['2'].$dob['1']."19".$dob['3'].$dob['4'];
                                }                                
                           }elseif(strlen($dob) > 5 ){
                                $year_of_birth=$dob['4'].$dob['5'];
                                if($year_of_birth < date('y')){
                                    $date_of_birth= "20".$dob['4'].$dob['5']."-".$dob['2'].$dob['3']."-".$dob['0'].$dob['1'];
                                    $dob_username= $dob['0'].$dob['1']."-".$dob['2'].$dob['3']."-20".$dob['4'].$dob['5'];
                                }else{
                                    $date_of_birth= "19".$dob['4'].$dob['5']."-".$dob['2'].$dob['3']."-".$dob['0'].$dob['1'];
                                    $dob_username= $dob['0'].$dob['1']."-".$dob['2'].$dob['3']."-19".$dob['4'].$dob['5'];
                                }
                           }
                        }
                        $first_name=$file_data['First name'];
                        $last_name=$file_data['Last name'];

                        $dateOfBirth = str_replace("-", '', $dob_username);

                        if((strlen($last_name) < 3 ) && (strlen($first_name) < 3 ) ){
                            $username=$last_name.$dateOfBirth.$first_name; 
                         }elseif(strlen($last_name) < 3 ){
                            // $username=$last_name.$dateOfBirth.substr($first_name, 0, 3);
                            $username=$last_name.$dateOfBirth. mb_substr($first_name, 0, 3,'UTF-8'); 
                         }elseif(strlen($first_name) < 3){
                             $username=mb_substr($last_name, 0, 3,'UTF-8').$dateOfBirth.$first_name;
                         }else{
                             $username=mb_substr($last_name, 0, 3 ,'UTF-8').$dateOfBirth.mb_substr($first_name, 0, 3,'UTF-8');
                         }
                        //echo $username."<br/>";

                        if($user_datas = $this->user_model->user_exist(array('username'=>$username))){
                            //if user already exist then take the user_id
                            foreach($user_datas as $user_data){
                                $user_id=$user_data['id'];
                            }
                            //if the user is already in the project for this season
                            if($this->user_model->user_exist_in_project(array('project_id'=>$project_name,'student'=>$username,'season'=>$season))){
                                //check users first name and last name if exist
                                if($user_datas = $this->user_model->user_exist(array('first_name'=>$first_name,'last_name'=>$last_name))){
                                    //if match found then reject this data
                                    $rejected[]=array("error"=> $this->lang->line('student_already_in_project_in_season'),"line_number"=>$error_count);
                                }else{
                                    $accepted[]=$file_data;
                                }
                            }

                        }else{
                            $accepted[]=$file_data;
                        }

                    }


                    $error_count++;
            }
```

Comment: I think it's a terrible idea, even combining the 3 elements, you still have pretty high collision chances, meaning it's very possible that you might have a few cases of people named the same, and being born the same date. Aim for some uniqueness, maybe add part of the timestamp when the username is generated, or some kind of hash...

Comment: Are you required to use only this data or can you append some random values to the usernames for uniqueness?

Comment: @aleation Thank you aleation for reply, If i use timestamp for username it is possible that same student will be in next year sheet so how i will check that is it present in our database or not. Ex if user Raju Jain was in class 10th in 2013 and registered with unique user name ujgttggdfgsdfsh, when in year 2014 again we add users we have duplicate entry for Raju Jain with new username

Comment: @PetarZivkovic i need some logarithm from which i generate a unique username for a user and check whether it is old user or new one whenever i add new user. i hope you got my situation.

Possiblities :
Data from CSV - have firstname , lastname & DOB
Students of different class,
Same student will appear in different CSV sheets,
Every User have only one username

Comment: you need something unique to each individual so an email or a student number something that remains with them across multiple years. Names,DOB aren't unique and appending a random string won't work as you state you'll get multi year conflicts.

Comment: Thank you dave for suggestion but for a nursery class student it is not possible to provide email, i mean they don't have such unique thing with them. So only i have firstname , lastname & DOB. Also it is possible that DOB will be not available for some cases. Please help me to get out of it

Answer (score 2):

My answer is going to address the specific problem you had regarding:

> I need a solution from which i generate a unique username with
>   available details also can check that a every student enters in
>   database only one time and have only one username.

Because you stated that you have "first name", "last name" and "birthday" (which might be null) for each student, and need to create a unique username, I'm going to suggest using a checksum.

The real problem is that the data you have cannot in itself guarantee uniqueness, so even the solution I will suggest is not going to work 100% without you implementing some sort of random salt in the user data.

Here is a code snippet to help you see what I'm thinking:

```
$fname = "John";
$lname = "Doe";
$bday  = "1980-03-01";

$unique_user_string = strtolower($fname . $lname . $bday); // not actually unique if 2 people have same name and birthday
$username = ucfirst(substr($fname, 0, 1)) . ucfirst($lname) . crc32($unique_user_string);
```

From the above code, you should have a username like: **JDoe4246458655**

And the nice part is that you can always confirm an existing user by checking the checksum and creating a new one using the user data from your CSV. To get the checksum from the existing username, just do:

```
$crc = substr($username, -10, 10);
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you Peter for answer, but if these details repeat for some other user than or get similar detail in next year sheet than next year John Doe again got a new user name. Means with every year they have new login details along with previous one and it conflicts database. I hope i am clear ?

Comment: @RajuJain, in the example above, the username is unique to the first name/last name/birthday combination. If someone has the *exact* same details, then the same username will be calculated… that is the downside to not having a truly unique identifier such as a student number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function simplly:

```
$uniqueid2 = md5(uniqid());
$uniqueid = substr($uniqueid2, 0, 8);
```

And add this $uniqueid variable at the end of their name, so this could lead you to a very unique login.

Comment: How can i check for wheteher same user registered with us in previous year.

For ex Raju Jain was registered with us in 2013 and in 2014 his name apperas again than we will add redundant entry for Raju Jain in database. From your code it may possible that every year user have new credentials.

Comment: No No, aisa nhi. This code only works when user registered his name with your site (only once), and after registeration, this will be his unique name for years. Got it ?

Comment: :-) Dear, i think you don't read question properly users are not register themself from a registration form. They got register on portal from data we read through a CSV file which we got from schools. Every year we got new CSV files, but it may possible next year CSV file contains previous year users/student also. So as per your logic same users will have different login credentials every year. Clear now

Comment: then you should ensure firstly that you have a record of the particular user with same name and dob, and before inserting check previous records with the same name + dob. So if you would found any previous records, then no need to generate a unique id, use the previous one, but if you wouldn't found any, then you can use my code to generate a new id. got it ?